# Pygame DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, pygame

I just installed Pygame 1.9.2.
When I try to run Pygame I get the error message "ImportError: DLL load failed"

I'm running Python 3.5 32bit, with a Pygame version for 3.4. Can this be the problem?
Unfortunatly i didnt find a version for Python 3.5

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The ABI can change between minor version releases, so compiled libraries from one minor version (3.4, for example) won't work with the interpreter from another minor version like 3.5. If you need `pygame` for 3.5, you'll have to build it yourself.

Comment: I fear my Pyhton knowledge is not good enough to do that. Anyway, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated earlier by MattDMo, there might be some ABI changes in between Python 3.4 and Python 3.5.

To save you the hassle, an unofficial PyGame 1.9.2 build for Windows is available [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Comment: Thanks for the link! It works perfectly fine with this version.